# Rails migration appears completed, but rake still shows migration as pending

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-migration, rails-migrations, mysql2

I ran a simple rails migration on a large MySql2 db to add a column to a table:

```
class AddMiddleNameToPerson < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :person, :middle_name, :string
  end
end
```

I was disconnected from the server running the rails app during the migration. I then reconnected and checked the migration status with `bundle exec rake db:migrate:status`, which showed it as down:

```
down    20170424182410  Add middle name to person
```

I assume it was still running in the background. So I left it for some time, and eventually using the rails console I verified that person.middle_name was accessible on objects. However, `db:migrate:status` still shows the migration as down, and if I try to run `db:migrate` again I get an error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'middle_name'
```

So it seems that the new column is in the database, and accessible through ActiveRecord, but `rake db:migrate:status` finds the migration as `down` and `rake db:migrate` attempts to re-run it, unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a production database (or other database with important data) then **do not** `rake db:reset` as that will drop the database and you'll lose everything; also **don't** `db:migrate:down` as that will drop the `middle_name` column and you'll lose whatever middle names you already have.

First get a backup of the database or at least the table you're working with.

Second, connect to the database with the `mysql` CLI tool and say `describe people;`. The information in your question suggests that you will see the `middle_name` column in there but it doesn't hurt to make sure you're connecting to the right database. If `middle_name` isn't there then you're almost certainly connecting to the wrong database somewhere, if it is there then you just have a migration issue to clean up.

You say that the database connection was dropped before the migration finished. Migrations work in this sequence:

1. Run the migration to update the database.
2. Record the migration's version number in the `schema_migrations` table.
3. Regenerate `db/schema.rb` or `db/structure.sql`.

If **1** completes but the connection is lost then **2** never happens so the migration will have run but Rails won't know it.

If no other environments need the migration then you can simply delete the migration and `rake db:schema:dump` or `rake db:structure:dump` to get a fresh `schema.rb` or `structure.sql`. Migrations are just temporary bits of code to get you from A to B so deleting them after they've been run everywhere is fine (and even recommended), all that matters long term is your database's structure (which is in `db/schema.rb` or `db/structure.sql`).

If other environments need to run the migration then you can manually patch the `schema_migrations` table; connect to the database with the `mysql` CLI tool and say `insert into schema_migrations (version) values ('20170424182410');`. Rails will now know that the migration was run and future `rake db:migrate` calls will be happy. Then you'd want to refresh your `schema.rb` (with `rake db:schema:dump`) or `structure.sql` (with `rake db:structure:dump`).

---

You probably have a `db/schema.rb` file for tracking your database's structure (including the version numbers of the migrations that have been run). If you do then you'd use `rake db:schema:dump` to regenerate it. If you have `db/structure.sql` then you'd use `rake db:structure:dump`.

Comment: Ended up doing something similar to this to get it resolved. Accepting.